# Getting first word of each line in file

Tags: c++

I have problem while getting first word of each line in my file. My txt file is:

```
GB LONDON 1 9 3 0 4 5
D BERLIN 2 5 6 1 4 
E MADRYT 1 2 3 4 5
```

And I want only to put  first word each line of file to array like [GB,D,E];
I tried this:

```
ifstream plik("galerie.txt");
    
    if(!plik){
        
        
        cout<<"not working";
    }

    
    string city[50];
    int n=0;
    while(plik.eof()){
        plik>>city[n];
    
        n++;
    
    }
    plik.close();
```

But it gets me every string in line like: GB,LONDON,1,9...

Comment: try [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Yes, I tried, but how can I use getline till whitespace because I tried this: getline(plik,city[n],' '); and stillnot working

Comment: `while(plik.eof())` is certainly a typo, but see why the intended `while(!plik.eof())` [is also wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: Even if I changed it, still not working

Comment: BTW, your program is ignoring the `if` statement.  The file will be read if the input open fails.  Maybe you want to `return` an error code instead of continuing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this code works fine for me can check on your side. You just need to push in vector instead of output in another file.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    vector<std::string> v;
    string line;
    string word;

    int i;
    int count=0;

    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin,line);
        for(i=0;i<line.length();i++)
        {
            if(line[i]==' ')
            {
                break;
            }
            word = word + line[i]
        }
        v.push_back(word);
        word = "";
    }
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << v[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: I agree with the above comments, I am unsure why this broken code was accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: A word in english language is until there is white space so we are checking for it in for loop within while loop if there is a condition satisfied for white space we will break for loop and go to next line.

Comment: We understand that however the code is broken in the way the two comments above mine point out.

Comment: Have you ran at your side?

Comment: `cout<<line;` is definitely a bug. And it does exactly what @churill mentioned.

Comment: Yeah but please try with int once its just a concept no need to copy paste

Comment: It's an answer to a question, and it doesn't compile. You should not be answering questions with broken code.

Comment: Yeah got it bro @churill thanks for pointing it out fixing it

Comment: Also that sentence _"You just need to push in vector instead of output in another file."_ - OP doesn't have any vector (but maybe should). So it would be nice if you could actually show how to solve this with a vector. If you need some time to fix the answer you can always delete it, [edit], then undelete again.

Comment: @churill try now might fix your issue (y)

Comment: Yeah but I liked your answer also less code more work done (y)

Comment: Now you removed the `getline` and broke the code again. I suggest you test the code before uploading it. You might want to fix the [`while(!fin.eof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) also.

Comment: Specifically, `word` is never used, and `line` is never given a value.

Comment: @churill it should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::ifstream plik("galerie.txt");

  if (!plik) {
    std::cerr << "not working";
    return 1;
  }

  std::vector<std::string> city;
  std::string tmp;
  while (std::getline(plik, tmp)) {
    city.push_back(tmp.substr(0, tmp.find_first_of(" ")));
  }
  plik.close();

  for (auto i : city) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
GB
D
E
```

Optionally, if you don't want `tmp` staying in scope longer than it's needed:

```cpp
  for (std::string tmp; std::getline(plik, tmp);) {
    city.push_back(tmp.substr(0, tmp.find_first_of(" ")));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to keep the first word you have read a single word and ignore the rest of the line. You can use [`std::istream::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to do so.

```
// read first word of a line
while(plik >> city[n]) 
{
    // skip rest of the line, including the line break
    plik.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    n++;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

! After reading again the question, code is changed and explanation is changed twice!

You are reading word by word without throwing away the words after the first one on each line, and appending it to the string.
I guess the best is to read a line and evaluate that, smiliar to Syed has proposed.

```
ifstream plik("galerie.txt");

if(!plik){
    
    
    cout<<"not working";
}


std::string city;
std:: istringstream streamCity;
std::string line;

streamCity << '[';

while (std::getline(plik, line)) {
    std::string cCode;
    std::istringstream iss(line);        
    iss>>cCode;
    streamCity << cCode << ',';

     n++;

}

streamCity << ']';
plik.close();
```

Comment: They are not reading character-by-character.

Comment: According to "http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/" the line "plik>>city[n];" reads one character and stores it in city[n].

Comment: Of course `std::cin` **can** read into a single character. This code doesn't do that.

Comment: `city[n]` is a `std::string` not a `char`. city is an array of std::string

Comment: Ok, OMG, you are right! Completely overseen... Sorry.